# ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5 while running jobs in Airflow

Tags: celery, airflow, airflow-scheduler

We have installed Airflow 2.1.3 version in Linux server, worker is also available in the same server and while we are trying to run the job it says

```
Error: ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5

airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Celery command failed on host ******
```

Task level log:

```
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. The request to ':///' is missing either
```

Currently using Python 3.6.8 version.

Is there any way to overcome this issue.

Comment: Have you tried running the celery worker on a separate machine?

Comment: @floating_hammer Yes , i have tried and running fine . You mean separate machine means separate python version or separate OS or seperate Hosts ?

Comment: maybe I was not clear separate physical hosts.

Comment: @floating_hammer .. Yes , I have tried and its working. But when i am trying with Python3.6.8 its not working :(

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need that version of python??

Comment: @floating_hammer.. Yes , as per admin approvals we are supposed to use 3.6.8 version and we cant use 3.8+ version

Comment: Have you set up `celery_result_backend` in the airflow.cfg when you are running the server and worker on the same machine?

Comment: @floating_hammer .. I am running webserver/scheduler in one server & worker in other server.. both the servers are with python3.6.8 version..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using k8s and I had the same problem.
In my case, the problem is because the python version was 3.7.
So, I change my tag version from 2.2.3 to 2.2.3-python3.8 and it  works